# Unable to replace all as expected in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I know that there are already questions about find and replace in r, but I am encountering weird issues.

Working data

```
a <- runif (5)
b <- letters [1:10]
c <- c(rep ("c-1", 4), rep(“c_5”, 6))
dt <- data.frame (a, b, c)
dt
    
    a     b   c
0.5685937 a c-1
0.1136978 b c-1
0.9842870 c c-1
0.7871407 d c-1
0.1031224 e c_5
0.5685937 f c_5
0.1136978 g c_5
0.9842870 h c_5
0.7871407 i c_5
0.1031224 j c_5
```

Expected output

```
a     b   c
0.5685937 a c.1
0.1136978 b c.1
0.9842870 c c.1
0.7871407 d c.1
0.1031224 e c.5
0.5685937 f c.5
0.1136978 g c.5
0.9842870 h c.5
0.7871407 i c.5
0.1031224 j c.5
```

I tried the following code,

```
dt$c2 <- gsub("-",".",dt$c)
dt$c2 <- gsub("_",".",dt$c)
```

but the format of 'c-1' didn't change

```
a     b   c
0.5685937 a c-1
0.1136978 b c-1
0.9842870 c c-1
0.7871407 d c-1
0.1031224 e c.5
0.5685937 f c.5
0.1136978 g c.5
0.9842870 h c.5
0.7871407 i c.5
0.1031224 j c.5
```

Anyone knows where is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pipe in the new column to `gsub()`, in the second call to that function:

```r
dt$c2 <- gsub("-", ".", dt$c)
dt$c2 <- gsub("_", ".", dt$c2)   # <-- pass in dt$c2, not dt$c here
```

But, I would just use a character class here with a single call to `gsub` in practice:

```r
dt$c2 <- gsub("[_-]", ".", dt$c)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second step you are actually overwriting the values written in the first step. Combine the `gsub` command into one.

```
dt$c2 <- gsub("-|_",".",dt$c)

dt
#           a b   c  c2
#1  0.3959316 a c-1 c.1
#2  0.4614878 b c-1 c.1
#3  0.7252994 c c-1 c.1
#4  0.4700026 d c-1 c.1
#5  0.9995240 e c_5 c.5
#6  0.3959316 f c_5 c.5
#7  0.4614878 g c_5 c.5
#8  0.7252994 h c_5 c.5
#9  0.4700026 i c_5 c.5
#10 0.9995240 j c_5 c.5
```